# Modify pandas data frame values based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a data frame with 9,000+ records (rows), a column with unique IDs, and each ID can have multiple records as shown below.

`df.head(4)`

| Unique_ID | Record_1 | Record_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AN5001 | 90.0 | ten |
| AN5002 | 90.0 | five |
| AN5001 | 95.0 | five |
| AN5003 | 60.0 | forty |

There are 360 unique IDs. However, about half of them need to be corrected. Consider below `df_corrected_ID.head(3)`

| Unique_ID_old | Unique_ID_new |
| --- | --- |
| AN5001 | AN5010 |
| AN5002 | AN5002 |
| AN5003 | AN5011 |

How would you, most efficiently, fix the Unique ID in the main `df` with 9,000+ records using the `df_corrected_ID` data frame?

So, check if **Unique_ID_old** is present in `df['Unique_ID']` column and if it is, replace it with **Unique_ID_new** from `df_corrected_ID`.

How would one then check change occurred correctly (for example, just show the difference between the Unique_IDs -- say after converting the original and updated columns to lists and then, `list(set(Unique_ID) - set(Unique_ID_new))`.

It's okay to add another new column to original `df` if needed with corrected IDs, as long as the order is maintained an none of the records are changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) for this. Make your corrected ID DataFrame into a dictionary that maps old IDs to new ones, and you can use it to update your existing column or create a new one.

```
update_dict = dict(zip(df_corrected_ID['Unique_ID_old'], df_corrected_ID['Unique_ID_new'])

# to create a new column
df['Unique_ID_updated'] = df['Unique_ID'].replace(update_dict)

# to update the existing column
df['Unique_ID'] = df['Unique_ID'].replace(update_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple mapping. You can add a column or update in place.

```
df_map = pd.DataFrame(dict(uni=['AN5001','AN5002','AN5003'], uni_update=['AN5010','AN5002','AN5011'])) 
df_record = pd.DataFrame(dict(uni=['AN5001','AN5002','AN5001','AN5003'], rec1=[1,2,3,4], rec2=['a','b','c','d']))
    
df_record['uni_update'] = df_record.uni.map(dict(zip(df_map.uni, df_map.uni_update)))
```

df w/ new col

```
|    | uni    |   rec1 | rec2   | uni_update   |
|---:|:-------|-------:|:-------|:-------------|
|  0 | AN5001 |      1 | a      | AN5010       |
|  1 | AN5002 |      2 | b      | AN5002       |
|  2 | AN5001 |      3 | c      | AN5010       |
|  3 | AN5003 |      4 | d      | AN5011       |
```

to check afterwards

```
df_record_reduced = df_record.drop_duplicates(subset='uni').loc[:,['uni','uni_update']].reset_index(drop=True)

|    | uni    | uni_update   |
|---:|:-------|:-------------|
|  0 | AN5001 | AN5010       |
|  1 | AN5002 | AN5002       |
|  2 | AN5003 | AN5011       |

df_map.equals(df_record_reduced) #should be true if everything is aligned
```